# Laravel return response()->json() against the return of just an array

Tags: php, json, laravel

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses) says:

> The `json` method will automatically set the `Content-Type` header to
>   `application/json`

But if I have a route in `api.php` or `web.php` and return an array in it, that header is also put.

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    return [
        'test' => 'test'
    ];
});
```

[image]

Does it make sense to write extra code `response()->json(...)` if you can do so?

Comment: Yes it does make sense, for whoever is reading the code after you. I bet that when you send a request with a header `accept: application/json` Laravel will try to return JSON. It may be the case that if you return "non HTML" (no `view()`) it tries to convert to JSON.

Comment: when we are sending post json data in an api. In laravel we will get it as an array because it is post request and we will get it as $request->all().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on you. When ever you return any value that is like collection and arrays, Laravel automatically transforms it as JSON (I have never noticed the application/json header though) and also with this is status code 200.

The implication is if you don't want Laravel to set the header for you and also the status code then use, `response()->json([...], status_code_here)`.

Comment: Relevant Laravel documentation entry: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#strings-arrays